# "proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations" ao instalar pacote no R

Tags: r, packages

Estou tentando instalar o **tmap** no R e aparece

> Installing package into ‘/home/americo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   also installing the dependencies ‘lwgeom’, ‘tmaptools’, ‘stars’

o seguinte erro aparece quando ele tenta instalar 'lwgeom'

> configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘lwgeom’

Estou rodando R-studio no Linux Mint. Já tentei instalar o libproj-dev no terminal e baixando o deb. Sempre diz que já está instalado.

Também já instalei o **rgdal**. Deu tudo certo, mas o erro continua para o **tmap**

Alguém sabe dizer qual o problema? Como posso consertar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após dias pesquisando, a única solução encontrada que funcionou para mim, foi instalar o lwgeom numa versão mais antiga.

Há a opção de instalar **lwgeom versão 0.2-2** que, segundo as discussões, não possui esse erro, a partir de:

> https://github.com/r-spatial/lwgeom

Mas, para o *meu* computador, a única versão que funcionou foi:

**lwgeom 0.1-7**

> https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lwgeom/lwgeom_0.1-7.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Tente esse comando no R: remotes::install_github("r-spatial/lwgeom"). Deu certo na versão 3.6.3. Inclusive você terá a versão 0.2-4. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Essa solução eu havia encontrado mas não funcionou no meu pc! Não sei se é coisa do Linux ou do R, mas vira e mexe tem algum pepino pra resolver. Mesmo assim, obrigado pela resposta! Espero que ajude outras pessoas